# Combine 2 tables in MySQL and create a new one

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables in MySQL:

Table 1

```
age code
20  ABC
15  DEF
32  ABC
45  DEF
```

Table 2

```
geo       code
POLYGON   ABC
POLYGON   DEF
POLYGON   GHI
```

1. I counted the double registers with the same "code" on table 1

   SELECT `code`, COUNT(`code`) AS cnt
   FROM table1
   GROUP BY `code`
   HAVING (cnt > 0)

resulted:

```
code  cnt
ABC    2
DEF    2
```

I want to combine this result with Table 2 and create a third table:

Table 3

```
geo      code   cnt
POLYGON  ABC     2
POLYGON  DEF     2
POLYGON  GHI     0
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Try INSERT INTO <new table> SELECT (<your JOIN query>) ?

Comment: And before that you have to create <new table>

Comment: no, you dont. you can do it all at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a table from the output of a query, by using `create table <tablename> as <query>` syntax.

So all we really have to do now is craft a query that returns the results you want. Here is one such query:

```
select geo, t2.code, ifnull(cnt, 0) cnt
  from table2 t2
    left join
      (select code, count(*) cnt
         from table1
         group by code
       ) q1
     on t2.code = q1.code
```

[demo fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75c40/3)

Then all we have to do is plug that into our `create table` statement.

```
create table new_table as
select geo, t2.code, ifnull(cnt, 0) cnt
  from table2 t2
    left join
      (select code, count(*) cnt
         from table1
         group by code
       ) q1
     on t2.code = q1.code;
```

and here's a bonus query that gets exactly the same results:

```
select t2.geo, t2.code, count(t1.code) cnt
  from table2 t2
    left join table1 t1
      on t1.code = t2.code
  group by t2.code;
```

[updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75c40/5)

Comment: Now if I want to be sure if the table "new_table" exists or not to create it. It would be: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `new table`;